# how to store somthing from session

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I have a login system in my site. in which session starts when user login. when a user sign up his information is stored in userdb.php .now i want to store point of the user when he clicks link www.stackoverflow.com and save it to my database or userdb.php.and again display point.
my sign up code are**

```html
<?php
if (session_id() == "")
{
   session_start();
}
$database = './usersdb.php';
$success_page = './Inside.php';
$error_message = "";
if (!file_exists($database))
{
   die('User database not found!');
   exit;
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['form_name'] == 'signupform')
{
   $newusername = $_POST['username'];
   $newemail = $_POST['email'];
   $newpassword = $_POST['password'];
   $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
   $newfullname = $_POST['fullname'];
   $code = 'NA';
   if ($newpassword != $confirmpassword)
   {
      $error_message = 'Password and Confirm Password are not the same!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$/", $newusername))
   {
      $error_message = 'Username is not valid, please check and try again!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$/", $newpassword))
   {
      $error_message = 'Password is not valid, please check and try again!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$.' &]{1,50}$/", $newfullname))
   {
      $error_message = 'Fullname is not valid, please check and try again!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^.+@.+\..+$/", $newemail))
   {
      $error_message = 'Email is not a valid email address. Please check and try again.';
   }
   else
   if (isset($_POST['captcha'],$_SESSION['random_txt']) && md5($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['random_txt'])
   {
      unset($_POST['captcha'],$_SESSION['random_txt']);
   }
   else
   {
      $error_message = 'The entered code was wrong.';
   }
   $items = file($database, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
   foreach($items as $line)
   {
      list($username, $password, $email, $fullname) = explode('|', trim($line));
      if ($newusername == $username)
      {
         $error_message = 'Username already used. Please select another username.';
         break;
      }
   }
   if (empty($error_message))
   {
      $file = fopen($database, 'a');
      fwrite($file, $newusername);
      fwrite($file, '|');
      fwrite($file, md5($newpassword));
      fwrite($file, '|');
      fwrite($file, $newemail);
      fwrite($file, '|');
      fwrite($file, $newfullname);
      fwrite($file, '|1|');
      fwrite($file, $code);
      fwrite($file, "\r\n");
      fclose($file);
      $subject = 'Your new account';
      $message = 'A new account has been setup.';
      $message .= "\r\nUsername: ";
      $message .= $newusername;
      $message .= "\r\nPassword: ";
      $message .= $newpassword;
      $message .= "\r\n";
      $header  = "From: webmaster@yourwebsite.com"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Reply-To: webmaster@yourwebsite.com"."\r\n";
      $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
      $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
      mail($newemail, $subject, $message, $header);
      header('Location: '.$success_page);
      exit;
   }
}
?>
```

Please help me.....

Comment: use $_SESSION. just search that on [Google](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it by using ajax..if you want save points..
like you have a link

```
<a href="" id="stack-overflow">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
Now in your js file:
$('#stack-overflow').on('click', function() {
count = 1//how many points you want to assign
//send a ajax
$.ajax({
  url:'usersdb.php',
  type:'GET'
  dataType: 'json'
  data: {
   points: count,
      },
  success: function(resp){
  $('#stack-overflow').href='www.stackoverflow.com';
  //now triggered this link
  $('#stack-overflow').click();
  //or what ever msg you want to display
  });
  });
```

//Now u can get $_POST values in your usersdb.php and save it

if there is another issue the please confirm...and tell me what actually you want.
Thanks.

Comment: Can i use php for that

Comment: if your stackoverflow.com is external link for your site... then it will be possible using ajax. If it is your site link (for which you want give points) then it is possible using php

Comment: can you edit the post an make it ass php. pls upvote my question so i can upvte your answer

Comment: for which link you want to give points is your site(which userdb.php exist) or its external link...because in this case page will redirect to external link page

Comment: if you agree pls accept my answer so that i could vote up your post

Comment: can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315432/how-to-store-session-data-of-user

Comment: I wll accept  that answer If(yes){comment below yes}

Answer (score 0):

To store values in session you can just use the below syntax

```
$_SESSION['Desired variable name'] = value;
```